# Coldfusion web service problem solving

Tags: web-services, coldfusion

On CF 9.01, Windows Web Server 2008 R2, a web service has stopped running [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/241618/coldfusion-web-service-developed-error), so I'm trying to figure out the problem. I *think* the problem may have started when I applied the 9.01 hotfix.

I added a test.cfc to the server

```
<cfcomponent output="false">

    <cffunction 
          name = "echoString" 
          output = "no" 
          access = "remote" returntype="any">
        <cfargument required="true" name="inputString" type="string"/>
        <cfreturn arguments.inputString>
    </cffunction>

</cfcomponent>
```

and call it with

```
<cfinvoke webservice="https://nww.somedomain.nhs.uk/cfcs/test.cfc?wsdl" 
method="echoString" returnvariable="returnedString">
    <cfinvokeargument name="inputString" value="test string 2">
</cfinvoke>
```

and get the string response, but in the cf administrator the web service is not being added
when I invoke the web service for the first time as I think it should be.

Other than reinstalling CF or trying to roll back manually, any clues as to the problem or how I can test please?

I'm on  9,0,1,274733   . The https is not the problem I think. Firstly it was working fine then with no change to code it stopped. Secondly my test invocation of test.cfc works as expected over https.

If I hit https://nww.somedomain.nhs.uk/cfcs/test.cfc?wsdl (which works) or my problem cfc https://nww.somedomain.nhs.uk/cfcs/providerapi.cfc?wsdl directly in the browser they both correctly show the XML details.

However, invoking either of the CFCs does not add them to the active web services list in administrator.

I pasted the "echostring" method to my problem CFC (providerapi.cfc) and tried calling the method but I get a "webservice cannot be found" error. It's like the providerapi.cfc is cached , but I can't see it in administrator to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this verbatim on 9,0,1,274733 and it worked 100% fine. I am using Win 7 and I just tried it on my dev environment. The web service was added to the list in CF admin so you are correct to expect that.

Can you ensure that you can hit the URL direct (i.e. `https://nww.somedomain.nhs.uk/cfcs/test.cfc?wsdl`) in your browser and view source to see the WSDL XML?

One thing that jumps out is the use of `https://` in your web service invocation. Can you try it with just `http://` or even better against your localhost?

Comment: Updated, yes they both call directly, but neither add to administrator web services page.

Comment: In CF Admin, have you tried clearing the template and the component cache? That's under Server Settings -> Caching.

Comment: Good idea, I did so and now neither my test web service nor the original one work. Neither can I access the XML service description on direct calling https://nww.somedomain.nhs.uk/cfcs/test.cfc?wsdl in the browser any more, I just get a blank page.

Comment: Can still call  nww.somedomain.nhs.uk/cfcs/test.cfc and access through component browser